# Storing escaped mysqli characters in database but outputting them correctly with htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, security

I have a database sanitizing function that I use when the user enters some data into my website.  I escaping the mysqli characters with mysqli_real_escape_string(), but I wish to also output the content with htmlspecialchars().  The problem is, let's just say the user enters something with a single quote; that will be escaped by the sanitize function and will be output as \'.  Is there any way to store it like that, and then output it as '?

Comment: A: don't 'escape' inputs, use prepared statements.  B: sanitize at the earliest possible time, 'escape' (if you really, really have to) at the lastest possible time.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a database sanitizing function that I use when the user enters some data into my website.

**If you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), there is no need to do this**.  There is nothing unsafe about having a value like "D'Alejandro" in a database column.

[SQL injection problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) arise when SQL statements are built by interpolating user-supplied values into the statement text.  There is no reason any modern web application should do this.